# How to get the value from particular key using python?

Tags: python, json

```
resp = {
  "Name": "test",
  "os": "windows",
  "Agent": {
    "id": "2",
    "status": [
      {
        "code": "123",
        "level": "Info",
        "displayStatus": "Ready",
        "message": "running",
        "time": "2022-01-18T09:51:08+00:00"
      }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to get the time value from the JSON.
I tried the below code but faced error with dict

```
resp1 = json.loads(resp)
resp2 = resp1.values()
creation_time = resp2.get("Agent").get("status")
val= creation_time["time"]
print(val) ## Thrwoing error as dict_values has no 'get'
```

Any suggestion on python how to take this time values

Comment: sorry edited now

Comment: Remove `resp2 = resp1.values()` and add an index to the list returned by `get("status")`

Comment: `print ( type (val) )` if you are unsure what type val has .... remainder should solve itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Few problems I noticed**

1. You are trying to load a Dict type using the json's loads function which is supposed to get a string in json format (ex:  `'{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'`)
2. You tried to access resp2 before declaration (I guessed you meant "resp1?")
3. You're using resp3 without declaration.
4. You are missing `}`
5. You don't need the .value() function because it will return a list.
6. Also creation time is a list with one object, so you need to access it too.

Considering all this, you can change it as follows:

```py
import json
resp = '{ "Name": "test", "os": "windows","Agent": {"id": "2","status": [{"code": "123","level": "Info","displayStatus": "Ready","message": "running","time": "2022-01-18T09:51:08+00:00"}]}}'

resp1 = json.loads(resp)
creation_time = resp1.get("Agent").get("status")
val= creation_time[0]["time"]
print(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to access the dicts using `[]` like so:

```
resp = {"Name": "test", "os": "windows", "Agent": {"id": "2","status": [{"code": "123","level": "Info","displayStatus": "Ready","message": "running","time": "2022-01-18T09:51:08+00:00"}]}}
creation_time = resp["Agent"]["status"]
val= creation_time[0]["time"]
print(val)
```

Output:

```
2022-01-18T09:51:08+00:00
```

Comment: the response is in bytes and throwing byte indices must be integers or slices, not str